# Filter $cpt categories to omit certain category

Tags: categories, filters

I have 5 categories (with matching slug id's), 'deps', 'duo', 'five piece band' and 'soloist' as part of my 'portfolio' custom post type. I want to display everything but 'deps' on one page, and then just 'deps' on another seperate page.

I have split the portfolio templates into template-listing-cpt-portfolio and template-listing-cpt-portfolio-dep so all I need to do is figure out how to filter the first template and I can reverse the filtering for the -dep template...

The template-listing-cpt-portfolio looks as follows:

```
<?php
    $cpt          = 'cpt_portfolio';
    $cpt_taxonomy = 'portfolio_category';

    $isotope        = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_listing_isotope', true );
    $masonry        = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_listing_masonry', true );
    $columns        = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_listing_columns', true );
    $posts_per_page = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_listing_posts_per_page', true );

    $div_class   = '';
    $title_class = '';
    if ( 1 == $isotope || 1 == $masonry ) {
        $div_class   = 'list-isotope';
        $title_class = 'with-subtitle';
    }

    $item_classes = ci_theme_get_columns_classes( $columns );

    $args = array(
        'paged'     => ci_get_page_var(),
        'post_type' => $cpt,
    );

    if ( $posts_per_page >= 1 ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = $posts_per_page;
    } elseif ( $posts_per_page <= - 1 ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = - 1;
    }

    if ( 1 == $isotope ) {
        $args['posts_per_page'] = - 1;
    }

    $q = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<h2 class="section-title <?php echo esc_attr( $title_class ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

<?php if ( 1 == $isotope ): ?>
    <ul class="portfolio-filters">
        <li><a href="#" class="selected" data-filter="*"><?php _e( 'All Items', 'ci_theme' ); ?></a></li>
        <?php $cats = get_terms( $cpt_taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => 1 ) ); ?>
        <?php foreach ( $cats as $cat ): ?>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->slug ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="row <?php echo esc_attr( $div_class ); ?>">

    <?php while( $q->have_posts() ): $q->the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            $isotope_classes = '';
            if ( 1 == $isotope ) {
                $cats = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), $cpt_taxonomy );
                foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                    $isotope_classes .= ' ' . $cat->slug;
                }
            }
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $item_classes . $isotope_classes ); ?>">
            <?php
                if ( 1 == $masonry && 1 != $columns ) {
                    get_template_part( 'listing-masonry', get_post_type() );
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'listing', get_post_type() );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!-- /.row -->

<?php ci_pagination( array(), $q ); ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by different pages, do you mean page one and page 2 of a paginated query, or completely different pages

Comment: Hi Pieter, so the 'deps' category would display in a completely separate page using the template-listing-cpt-portfolio-dep page template, and the 'acts' category and it's relevant sub categories would display on a separate page using the template-listing-cpt-portfolio. I hope this answers your question.